# jscript for toggling a hamburger menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to fix some stuff left over by the front-end developer and I am not expert in javascript (not at all).

On our staging system we use a hamburger menu and for reasons unknown to me while the hamburger menu toggles perfectly on opening, upon first closing it doesn't revert back from an "X" to the "Hamburger" subsequent changes instead work flawlessly just that the state is inverted ("X" where there should be a hamburger and hamburger where there should be an "X").

So I did it half right (but only half :D).

My rather not beautyful code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var headerMobile = document.getElementsByClassName('header-mobile')[0];
var openMobileMenuTrigger = document.getElementById('open-mobile-menu'); 
var closeMobileMenuTrigger = document.getElementById('close-mobile-menu'); 
var mobileMainMenu = document.getElementById('header-mobile_menu'); 
var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName('header-mobile_submenu');
var openMobileSubMenuTriggers = document.getElementsByClassName('open-mobile-submenu');
var closeMobileSubMenuTriggers = document.getElementsByClassName('close-mobile-submenu');  
var hamburgerHeader = document.getElementById('open-mobile-menu'); 
var openSearchTrigger = document.getElementById('open-search-field')
function toggleHamburger(){
    if (hamburgerHeader.classList.contains('is-active')){
        hamburgerHeader.classList.remove('is-active');  
    } else {
        hamburgerHeader.classList.add('is-active');
    }
    
}

function toggleMobileMenu(){

    if(mobileMainMenu.classList.contains('is-active') !== true){
        if (openSearchTrigger)
            {openSearchTrigger.classList.remove('is-active')}
        mobileMainMenu.classList.add('is-active'); 
        headerMobile.classList.add('is-active'); //remove shadow
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.add('noscroll')// no scroll for html
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('noscroll')// no scroll for body
    } else {
        
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                // headerMobile.classList.remove('is-active'); // NO MORE SHADOW IF WE KEEP ACTIVE SEARCH MENU
                for (var i = submenus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    submenus[i].classList.remove('is-active');
                }
            }, 
            400 
        )
        if(openSearchTrigger){
            openSearchTrigger.classList.add('is-active')
        }
        hamburgerHeader.classList.remove('is-active')
        mobileMainMenu.classList.remove('is-active')
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.remove('noscroll')// no scroll for html
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.remove('noscroll')// no scroll for body
    }
}

function openMobileSubmenu(event){
    var submenuId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-submenu');
    document.getElementById('header-mobile_submenu-' + submenuId).classList.add('is-active'); 
}

function closeMobileSubmenu(){
    for (var i = submenus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        submenus[i].classList.remove('is-active'); 
    }
}

if (openSearchTrigger){
    openSearchTrigger.addEventListener('click', toggleMobileMenu);
}

openMobileMenuTrigger.addEventListener('click', toggleMobileMenu);
// closeMobileMenuTrigger.addEventListener('click', closeMobileMenu);

hamburgerHeader.addEventListener('click', toggleHamburger); 

for (var i = openMobileSubMenuTriggers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    openMobileSubMenuTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', openMobileSubmenu); 
}
for (var i = closeMobileSubMenuTriggers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    closeMobileSubMenuTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', closeMobileSubmenu);
}
```

Comment: Please share html and css.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I can see how that helps :D 
the page is ricomprostaging.it/shop/

Comment: @yasgo If you need more just ping me